# Steeltoe service registry discovery and prefixing a hostname to the resolved url

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, cloud-foundry, service-discovery

I am using PCF Service Registry to register my micro services and using discovery client to resolve the actual service urls for inter service calls like below

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CustomerController: Controller
    {
        private DiscoveryHttpClientHandler discHttpHandler;

        private ILogger<ValuesController> logger;

        private const string RANDOM_CUSTOMER_URL = "https://CustomerService/api/v1/customer/";

        //private const string RANDOM_CUSTOMER_URL = "http://localhost:58227/api/v1/customer/";

        public CustomerController(IDiscoveryClient client, ILogger<ValuesController> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.discHttpHandler = new DiscoveryHttpClientHandler(client);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the customer name by invoking Customer Service via 
        /// Service registry lookup
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("GetCustomerName/{id}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerName(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = GetClient();
                var resString = await client.GetAsync(RANDOM_CUSTOMER_URL + id).
                    Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var respObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse<CustomerDTO>>(resString);
                if (respObj != null)
                {
                    return Ok(new { CustomerName = respObj.Result.FirstName + ", " + respObj.Result.LastName });
                }
                return NotFound();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(default(EventId), ex, ex.ToString());
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create an Http client backed by Steeltoe's DiscoveryHttpClientHandler
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private HttpClient GetClient()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient(discHttpHandler, false);
            return client;
        }
    }
```

This is working fine and I am able to resolve the target service url. But there is a new requirement to support an access gateway host name like the resolved url should be prefixed with the dns name of access gateway like http://GatewayUrl/CustomerService/api/v1/customers. I don't know how to accomplish this in Eureka configuration. I tried to put the hostname in eureka:instance configuration as mentioned in http://steeltoe.io/docs/steeltoe-discovery/, but ended up being the same url resolved as before. Any thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to register your service with a non-automatically configured hostname, place the host name in `eureka:instance:hostName` AND set `eureka:instance:registrationMethod` to `hostname`

Comment: "eureka": {
    "client": {
      "shouldRegisterWithEureka": true,
      "shouldFetchRegistry": false
    },
    "instance": {
      "statusPageUrlPath": "/api-docs/swagger",
      "healthCheckUrlPath": "/HealthCheck",
      "hostName": "customerservice1-mycomp.net",
      "registrationMethod": "hostname"
    }
  }  I have registered my target service like above. And in my source service, I am using the Url https://CUSTOMERSERVICE/api/v1/customer/ to resolve. But looks like after giving a wrong host name also, it is working(means some other registration method is in action).